when will the irreversible work be greater than the reversible work?
i was told that a reversible process does more work than irreversible process because no energy is lost to heat/friction. Then in clausius inequality derivation, there is an inequality that said
Work irreversible - Work reversible is greater than or equal to 0
How can this be? wouldn't it mean that irreversible work is greater than reversible work?
maybe i misunderstand something but i can't figure out where i went wrong.

The irreversible work done by a system in expansion is not always less than the reversible work between the same pair of end states.  There are an infinite number of reversible paths between the end states, and, for some paths, the reversible work is less than the irreversible work (although the entropy change for all the reversible paths is the same).  To see how this plays out, please see the following link:  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/focus-problem-for-entropy-change-in-irreversible-adiabatic-process.1054165/

Irreversible work done on the system (compression) is bigger than reversible work. The extra irreversible work is converted to extra heat.
Irreversible work done by the system (expansion) is less than reversible work. The lost irreversible work has be spent by conversion to extra heat.
The irreversibility need not to be due friction, but it can be caused by anything diverging from equilibrium state during the process. E.g. sudden pushing or releasing a piston.

There are two sign convention for work, related to changes of system internal energy and the 1st law of thermodynamics:

$\Delta U = Q + W$ : Currently prevailing convention in science and chemistry: Work done on the system is positive, work done by system is negative, focusing on internal energy of the system.
$\Delta U = Q - W$ : Historical convention of physics and engineering, focusing on engines and useful work: Work done by system is positive, work done on the system negative.

Imagine the exchanged reversible work is $\pu{50 J}$ and irreversible deviation is $\pu{10 J}$.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Work at below processes} & \Delta U = Q + W &  \Delta U = Q - W \\
\hline
\text{Reversible compression} & W = +\pu{50 J} & W = -\pu{50 J} \\
\text{Irreversible compression} & W = +\pu{60 J} & W = -\pu{60 J} \\
\text{Reversible expansion} & W = -\pu{50 J} & W = +\pu{50 J} \\
\text{Irreversible expansion} & W = -\pu{40 J} & W = +\pu{40 J} \\
\hline
\end{array}

Poutnik's answer is perfectly correct. But the confusion made by Siswa Jose is probably due to the method for defining the work. The work due to a volume change of a gas is always the integral of $p$d$V$. But the same integral of $p$d$V$ can be positive or negative, depending on the origin of the author. I explain.
For chemists, and for IUPAC, all energies entering a system are positive. Work is an energy. So, when pushing a piston into a syringe to let a gas entering a system, the total gas volume decreases, but the corresponding work is positive. $w = -\int p\mathrm{d}V$. Please observe the minus sign in front of the integral.
For some engineers, it is different. A thermal machine is a device that is heated in order to produce a work, like an engine or a locomotive. In this setup, heat is positive, as it is given to the engine. But work is also positive, if the machine is working properly. So for engineers (specially in America), work is positive when this work is produced by the machine. $w = +\int p\mathrm{d}V$. This concept is the contrary of what IUPAC and the chemists think. This may have troubled Siswa Jose.
As a final conclusion, we will now state that these two opposed ways of defining the work have no effet on the calculation of internal energy $U$.
For both chemists and engineers, the change of internal energy $U$ due to a change of gas volume is equal to $\Delta U$ =  $Q - \int p\mathrm{d} V$.
For IUPAC and chemists, the same expression can be written $\Delta U$ =  $ Q$ - $ w$
For engineers, the same expression can be written  $\Delta U$ =  $ Q$ + $ w$
